# Two past verb(or past participles) arranged side by side in news headline

Tags: headline-english

> De Lima **ordered** arrested by RTC [link](http://news.abs-cbn.com/news/02/23/17/de-lima-ordered-arrested-by-rtc)

From this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/differences-in-meaning-when-the-verb-tense-changes-headlines)

I somewhat understand of Headlinese. However, I still don't understand *ordered*. I mean, I can understand *was* is omitted in following sentence.

> De Lima (*was*) arrested by RTC

But in the sentence, two past participles are arranged side by side. I tried to study Headlinese but I couldn't find answer clearly.

Could somebody make a perfect(normal) sentence from the headline? I read someone said it can be various cases. Then could you make some sentences which is possible to suppose.

So far, my best attempt is that

> De Lima *(was)* ordered *(to be)* arrested by RTC

I'm not sure, though.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've got it right.

Comment: @MetaEd Oops.. Is that right? Then this question became useless one... haha.

Comment: @MetaEd BTW, So we cannot notice if she was arrested already or not, from the headline.

Comment: That is also right.

Comment: Ting Choe, you may now answer your own question!  You could take some material out of your question and move it to your answer.  Then people will upvote it and you can also accept it.